# Get result after connecting to a VPN

Tags: c#, .net, vpn

I can connect to an existing VPN created with the following code.

```
string args = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", connVpnName, connUserName, connPassWord);
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\rasdial.exe",
        Arguments = args,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
proc.Start();
string output = "";
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    output += proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    txtOutput.Text += proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```

I need to know if the connection succeeded, the wrong credentials where used, the VPN doesn't excist or if the ip isn't online.

My first idea was to get the output from the commandprompt and search for keywords like "is connected". The problem with this method is that my users use multiple languages and the keywords will be different.

Can I use an other method to achieve this?

Comment: Could you ping a machine in the subnet to check if you are connected?

Comment: How about calling `RasDial` directly? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004(v=vs.85).aspx  Or detect a VPN connection by checking for changes in the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` WMI Class

Comment: Having no experience with `rasdial.exe` myself, I suggest that you try it on the command line with the same arguments. Does it work when you do it manually?

Comment: @Philippe: yes I can, but there are more than 200 VPN's that I need to be able to connect to( This program is for a helpdesk company) and I don't Always know the ip's there excist on the subnet.

Comment: @maartenvdv Ah, ok. I had implemented a solution like that where the connection would be checked periodically and re-established if required. It doesn't look viable for you though.

Answer (score 1):

use [DotRAS](http://dotras.codeplex.com/) this library is a wrapper around windows api. Almost all functions are documented in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

```
            proc.Start();

            //het resultaat bekijken
            proc.WaitForExit();
            switch (proc.ExitCode)
            {
                case 0: //connection succeeded
                    MessageBox.Show("Je bent geconnecteerd met de VPN");
                    isConnectedVPN = true;
                    btnConnectToVPN.Text = "Stop VPN";
                    break;
                case 691: //wrong credentials
                    MessageBox.Show("De username en/of het wachtwoord kloppen niet.");
                    break;
                case 623: // The VPN doesn't excist
                    MessageBox.Show("Deze VPN staat niet tussen de bestaande VPN's.");
                    break;
                case 868: //the IP or domainname can't be found
                    MessageBox.Show("Het ip-adres of de domeinnaam kan niet gevonden worden");
                    break;
                default: //other faults
                    MessageBox.Show("fout " + proc.ExitCode.ToString());
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: You can get the RAS error message by calling `GetRasErrorString` (http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/rasapi32/RasGetErrorString.html)